# json problem after including the new Extjs version 6.7

Tags: json, extjs, decode, extjs6

I want to upgrade the version of extjs from 6.5 to 6.7. in my application, after including the extjs 6.7 files and building the solution i get this error: Ext.JSON.decode(): You 're trying to decode an invalid JSON String.
Any solution please?

Comment: Can you attach the code of `Ext.JSON.decode()` usage ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the same problem I had when upgrading from 6.5. I think in version 6.6 they changed the structure of the response objects for store callbacks and instead of providing a responseText property that needed to be decoded into JSON, they provide a responseJson property that is already decoded.

So as a result, my code that had previously looked like this:

```
callback: function (records, request) {
    var response = Ext.decode(request.getResponse().responseText);
}
```

had to be changed to this:

```
callback: function (records, request) {
    var response = request.getResponse().responseJson;
}
```

I'm guessing you will have to do something similar to fix your issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i  just solved the problem, it's about USE_NATIVE_JSON. it must be equal to false Ext.USE_NATIVE_JSON = false;